# Period of a wind turbine

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[Question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kAwA.png)

Right the question is **hence or otherwise, find the time taken for each blade to complete one revolution**.

$h(t) = 65+36\sin(3/2t)-15\cos(3/2t)$

I guess you'd divide $2\pi/(3/2)$ and get $4/3 \pi$

Is that the answer, I'm not really to sure as I've never dealt with a sine and cosine function together.

Comment: Sorry "find the time taken for each blade to complete one revolution".

Comment: For future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: Also note that you can edit a question after posting it. So instead of making a comment about the text that you meant to include in the question but did not, just edit the question and put the text in it where it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

Your height is a periodic function of the time. You are looking for the period of this periodic function.

You see, the $\sin$ and the $\cos$ in your height function are linked together by addition or subtraction and have the same argument. That means, your height function has the same period as this $\sin$ and $\cos$. And you know, the period of the sinus function and of the cosinus function is $2\pi$. That means, the value of this functions are repeated all $2\pi$.

But you wants not the period, you wants the corresponding time. The period of the height function is $\frac{3}{2}t=2\pi$. The result is $t=\frac{4}{3}\pi$ s.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated :)